# Find a node in a binary search tree

Tags: c, search, binary-search-tree

My findNode is called in my insert function with the address of tree. Since im inserting the first word tree should be NULL but when I debug it skips over this check in my FindWords function.

Im not sure exactly what is the value of tree here if it is not NULL, please advise.

```
struct TREENODE {
    struct TREENODE *parent; // point to parent node of this node
    struct TREENODE *left; // point to left child of this node
    struct TREENODE *right; // point to right child of this node

    char *word; // store a unique word in the text file
    int count; // num of times this word appears in the file
};

typedef struct TREENODE NODE;
#define MAXWORDLEN  1000
```

when I insert the first word, tree should be NULL here because no words exist. But instead of this function returning NULL when no words exists its skips to the if statement (strcmp(word, tree->word == 0)) and causes a segmentation fault.

```
NODE* findNode(char *word, NODE* tree) {
  // return node storing word if exists
    if (tree == NULL){return NULL;}

    if (strcmp(word, tree->word)==0)
      return tree;
    if (strcmp(word, tree->word) <0)
          return findNode(word, tree->left);
    return findNode(word, tree->right);
 }


 void insertNode(char *word, NODE** address_of_tree ) {


    NODE *tree = *address_of_tree;
    NODE *node;
     node = findNode(word, tree); 
    if (node == NULL) {

    NODE *new_node = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    new_node->word = word;
    new_node->parent = *address_of_tree;
    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;

    if (tree == NULL) {
        *address_of_tree = new_node;
        return;
    }
    if (strcmp(word, tree->word) < 0) {
        // word must be added to left subtree
        if (tree->left !=NULL) insertNode(word, &tree->left);
        else {
            new_node->parent = tree;
            tree->left = new_node;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (tree->right != NULL) insertNode(word, &(tree->right));
        else {
            new_node->parent = tree;
            tree->right = new_node;
        }
      }
    }
     else {
        // update the count for the word
        node->count += 1;
    }

 }

void printTree(NODE* tree) {
    // print each word and its count in alphabetical order
    if (tree == NULL) return;
     printTree(tree->left);
     printf("word: %s\ncount: %d", tree->word, tree->count);
     printTree(tree->right);
}


int main() {
      // read text from stdin
      // each time we read a word
     // insert this word into the tree

     NODE *tree; // the tree we are using to store the words

     char word[MAXWORDLEN];
      while(scanf("%s", word) != EOF) {
        // insert this word into the tree
        insertNode(word, &tree);
     }

    printTree(tree);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: How do you initially call the `insertNode` function? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added a more specific spot of where I am having the issue and the rest of my code. Please advise

Comment: sorry, thanks for changing it

Answer (score 1):

You are taking input in buffer `word` and passing it to `insertNode()`. In the `insertNode()`, you are doing

```
new_node->word = word;
```

which will make all the new node `new_node->word` pointer point to same buffer `word`. Any changes in the content of `word` buffer will reflect in all the nodes `nodes->word` value. Instead, you should do

```
new_node->word = strdup(word);
```

`strdup()` duplicates the given string. It uses `malloc` to obtain memory for the new string. Make sure to free it once you are done with it.

You should also initialise the `tree` with `NULL` before creating tree

```
NODE *tree = NULL;
```

because you are passing `tree` pointer to `insertNode()` and in the `insertNode()` you are checking for `tree` pointer is `NULL` or not. So, you should explicitly initialise the `tree` pointer with `NULL`.

Comment: I tried both of these and I got a segmentation fault because in the insert Node function i call the findNode function so if you set the tree pointer to NULL then it automatically, says the NODE does not exist. In which case the count will always be zero.

Comment: @dark_deer where are you setting `tree` to `NULL`? You should set `tree = NULL` in the `main()` before entering `while` loop. Your `findNode()` function is having handling of `tree` when it is `NULL` (which is the terminating condition of recursion). So, there should not be any problem when calling `findNode()` when `tree` is `NULL`. With these two changes, when I run your code, I am getting proper output - Input : `a a a`, output : `word: a, count: 2`.